# Is this the right way to nested whereHas queries in eloquent way

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The first part with itemreceive works. But the second part, dispatchitem does not work.

I am retrieving the sum of itemreceive and dispatchitem. I am trying to achieve the inventory balance of the given months.

```
 $opens = Item::with(['itemreceive'=>function($q) use ($date){
                $q->whereHas('receive', function($query) use ($date){
                    $query->whereDate('datetime', '<=', $date->subMonth()->endOfMonth());
                });
            }], ['dispatchitem'=>function($r) use ($date){
                $r->whereHas('dispatch', function($result) use ($date){
                    $result->whereDate('datetime', '<=', $date->subMonth()->endOfMonth());
                });
            }])
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->get();

I expect both conditions in itemreceive and dispatchitem effective.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have entered wrong syntax for with. You need to insert one array in "with". Please use following code:

```
$opens = Item::with(['itemreceive'=>function($q) use ($date){
    $q->whereHas('receive', function($query) use ($date){
        $query->whereDate('datetime', '<=', $date->subMonth()->endOfMonth());
    });
}, 'dispatchitem'=>function($r) use ($date){
    $r->whereHas('dispatch', function($result) use ($date){
        $result->whereDate('datetime', '<=', $date->subMonth()->endOfMonth());
    });
}])
->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
->get();
```